# How to join Array to String (Java) in one line?

Tags: java, arrays, one-liner

Let's assume there is an array:

```java
String[] myArray = new String[]{"slim cat", "fat cat", "extremely fat cat"};
```

Now I want to transform this array into a String joined with `"&"`.
So that the output becomes:

```
slim cat&fat cat&extremely fat cat
```

I am trying to keep my code shorter and clean, without the need to manually type a `for` loop.

I would like to have a short solution, like we use in reverse way with `someString.split();`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It would help explaining why you don't want to use a `for` loop. Are `while` loops okay? Is hiding the loop in a helper method, library, the JDK okay?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using Java 8, [`String.join(CharSequence delimiter, CharSequence... elements)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-):

```
String result = String.join("&", myArray);
```

Using Java 7 or earlier, you either need a loop or recursion.

Comment: Super :) I'm thinking why this method was introduced only now, in Java8... Very useful.

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis I think a lot of people were thinking the same thing.  I'm wondering why Java *still* doesn't have a method to let you create a string by concatenating another string or character _n_ times, since it's something I need a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Use Guava's [`Joiner`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#joiner) or Java 8 [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html).

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Why without a for loop?

Use a StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append( myArray.remove(0));

for( String s : myArray) {
    builder.append( "&");
    builder.append( s);
}

String result = builder.toString();
```

Comment: He has clearly stated..How can I achieve this without using for loop?

Comment: We have simple way to do it reverse `someString.split();`. So I thought it should be some very simple way to create tokenized `String` from `Array`

Answer (score 1):

Use Apache Commons Lang, [`StringUtils.join(Object[] array, char separator)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20char)).

Example:

```java
String result = StringUtils.join(myArray, '&');
```

This library is also compatible with Java 7 and earlier. Plus, it has a lot of overloaded methods.

Comment: Benefit of Apache Commons compared to Java 8 (StringJoiner or String.join): it's **null-safe**.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this job without some sort of iteration over the array.  Even languages that offer some form of a `join()` function (which do not include Java < version 8) must internally perform some sort of iteration.

About the simplest way to do it in Java <= 7 is this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String result;

for (String s : myArray) {
    sb.append(s).append('&');
}
sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);

result = sb.toString();
```