# How would you print a list (not java lingo, a literal list) more easily?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I was working on a project, and thought, *Couldn't there be an easier way to write a list without having to waste 3 minutes and one line of code?* I'm probably wasting even more time here, but suppose I want to spell out "Hello, world!":

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array = {"H", "E", "L", "L", "O", ", ", "W", "O", "R", "L", "D", "!"};

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
            System.out.print(array[i] + "-"); // prints "H-E-L-L-O-, -W-O-R-L-D-!-"
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see there's a nagging dash hanging over the edge at the end of the line. One idea I had was doing this:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array = {"H", "E", "L", "L", "O", ", ", "W", "O", "R", "L", "D", "!"};
    System.out.print(array[0]); // enter "H" early
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) { // int i = 0 -> int i = 1
            System.out.print("-" + array[i]); // switched order, prints "H-E-L-L-O-, -W-O-R-L-D-!"
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, this does complete the job, but I feel like the extra line is clunky and awkward in my code. Also, I don't feel it's exactly flexible?
If there's something inside the documentary junk or a trick I need, please let me know. :)

Comment: `String.join("-", array)`?

Comment: See the various solutions on this answer, specifically the one for Java 8 `.join`: [How to join Array to String (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871663/how-to-join-array-to-string-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can print the dash before the list element and if the list element is the first one, you don't print anything.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array = {"H", "E", "L", "L", "O", ", ", "W", "O", "R", "L", "D", "!"};

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
            System.out.print((i == 0 ? "" : "-") + array[i]); // prints "H-E-L-L-O-, -W-O-R-L-D-!"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iterator `i` in a ternary expression `(i == array.length - 1 ? "" : "-")` as a substitute for the constant `"-"`. This way, whether or not there is a dash is dynamic, based on whatever you want. This is adaptable to lots of different scenarios.